# What are the uses of Adobe's RTMP protocol?

Tags: rtmp

What are the uses of Adobe's RTMP protocol?

Comment: Its the Real-Time Messaging Protocol; The name says it all... ;-)

Comment: wow, you guys really beat him up in the votes.. i think this is a useful question

Answer (score 6):

It's based on TCP and was specifically designed for streaming video, audio, and data between a media server and clients (Flash player). Currently applications like follows use this protocol:

- Online multi-player games
- Text and video chat applications
- Virtual meeting applications
- Synchronous and interactive e-learning applications (business simulation games, etc.)

Flash player natively supports RTMP (this protocol was developed by Adobe). At the server side, besides Adobe's Flash media server, there are Wowza and Red5 (open-source). These are most-widely used media server systems. There are also some open-source applications like [rtmpdump](http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/).

You can find more information about RTMP in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link where you can find more informations about RTMP

http://www.redcodelabs.com/2009/06/rtmp-specification-is-out/

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/rtmp.html

The Real-Time Messaging Protocol (RTMP) was designed for high-performance transmission of audio, video, and data between Adobe Flash Platform technologies, including Adobe Flash Player and Adobe AIR. RTMP is now available as an open specification to create products and technology that enable delivery of video, audio, and data in the open AMF, SWF, FLV, and F4V formats compatible with Adobe Flash Player.

Answer (score 2):

As you could have figured out by searching, [RTMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) is a proprietary media streaming protocol that can tunnel over TCP, HTTP, or HTTPS.

Do have a more specific question than "The title says it all"?